# GWT compile hangs

Tags: gwt

I created a Google Web Toolkit project in Eclipse (Indigo, GWT 2.4, Linux Ubuntu), made some changes (mainly, renamed the default module and added a new module), then clicked "GWT Compile", and then nothing happened - the compilation just hanged forever. There is no output; the progress bar at the bottom right shows "0%".

When I use "loglevel=all", I get a single line of output "Checking for updates" and then it hangs.

I tried deleting the cache - no change.

I tried creating a new project and copying the source files - no change.

With the help of this link: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.org.google.gwt/70561 I added "-XdisableUpdateCheck" to the compiler; now the compile completes, but, when I try to run in development mode ("Run as -> Web application") it says "Development mode is loading..." and hangs.

I don't know even how to start debugging this. Please give me some hint!

Comment: Have you set the debug level to TRACE or DEBUG yet?

Comment: yes, When I use "loglevel=all", I get a single line of output "Checking for updates" and then it hangs.

Comment: Is the compile operation maybe blocked by some other Eclipse operation (like Checking for updates)?

Comment: I don't think so; I closed and re-opened Eclipse, and retried many times, and always got the same results.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue. Here is my sequence of events for it:
Checked out the GWT project from the SVN --> tried to Google-GWT Compile --> gave entry point modules --> my log level was info and output style Obfoscated -->Hit compile.. Nothing happens except the progress bar stuck at 0%.
Tried to google and find out the solution in multiple ways but couldn't get the proper answer. 
One trick worked --> I deleted the project from the eclipse workspace and re-imported it from the disk as an existing project. GWT compile worked this time. :)

Why it worked? --> When we delete the project from eclipse workspace all the libraries associated with that project get unbound and removed from the classpath. When you again import the same project and try to compile GWT before adding the required libraries to the classpath it will works. The real conflict is with GWT libraries and JBoss 5.0 libraries. There looks like some plain bug in GWT2.4 which they need to resolve. In the classpath if you precede the jboss and Web App libraries prior to GWT library the compile gets stuck.

If you face the similar issue, remove jboss and web app libraries from the classpath and compile GWT module and then add those removed libraries sothat the JAva source from your project gets compiled. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem after working through this tutorial: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/12/securing-gwt-apps-with-spring-security.html

In the end it was a dodgy external JAR that I added to my build path (the spring-context one mentioned in the tutorial). I grabbed another copy of it and all is good now.

Comment: Thanks, but, that is probably not my problem as I don't have external jars in my project.

Comment: Can you speak anymore about this dodgy JAR as I am facing a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the FIX for this one as we cannot continue with this whole business of taking the jBoss library in and out every time we need to compile `GWT`.
The problem is that `com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.getCompilerOptions` 
(`JdtCompiler.java`) is referring to `CompilerOptions` which, as fate would have it, is referencing to the implementation in `jasper-jdt.jar` (situated in `jboss` library) instead of `gwt` specific implementation. Get ride of this `jasper-jdt.jar` from jBoss library and you should be all set. Don't worry if you absolutely need any of the classes from `jasper-jdt.jar`; there are tons of alternative Jasper jars who can fulfill your need other than this one.

Answer (score 0):

try this: right click->google->gwt compile->click advance (bottom) and
In the Additional compiler argument add this:

-XdisableUpdateCheck

Answer (score 0):

Giving option -XdisableUpdateCheck to GWT Compiler solves the deadlock problem for me. Thanks for the hint.

Used GWT 2.5.0 with java :

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_35"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_35-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.10-b01, mixed mode)


$ cat /etc/issue
Fedora release 18 (Spherical Cow)
Kernel \r on an \m (\l)


$ uname -a
Linux myhostname 3.9.4-200.fc18.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri May 24 20:10:49 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by setting the optimization level (console Argument `-optimize 8` to 8, which means optimize the code at most 8 times. Default is level 9 resulting in optimizing until nothing changes anymore. It seems there are a few cases where this results in an endless loop.

Also see this issue on GitHub:

https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/9452#issuecomment-259088434

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but today a colleage of mine was just running into this issue, too. It turned out that he was using classes from client packages (both own classes and ...client.rpc.IsSerializable) within the shared package of his project. 
As a result the GWT build froze at compiling permutation 0. I assume that it got trapped within an endless loop between compiling shared and client classes.
Removing all usages of client classes from shared classes helped.