# Make GWT Maven Plugin use -XdisableUpdateCheck flag during GWT compile

Tags: maven, gwt, gwt-maven-plugin

I have several GWT-based projects that won't compile unless the `"-XdisableUpdateCheck"` flag is passed to the GWT compiler.  I've been trying to mavenize these projects by using the `"gwt-maven-plugin"`; however, I can't seem to figure out a way to configure the `GWT Maven plugin` to use the `"-XdisableUpdateCheck"` flag during GWT compile.

Is there a way to tell the `GWT Maven plugin` to use such a flag during GWT compile?

Side Note: I am using `GWT 2.4 SDK` and can't really upgrade to any other version.

Comment: side note - my team recently updated from 2.4 to 2.5 and it was rather painless.

Answer (score 0):

Can extraJvmArgs help? [extraJvmArgs](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#extraJvmArgs)

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I have tried using "extraJvmArgs".  It seems  parameters passed via the "extraJvmArgs" make their way to the "Java.exe" executable and not the GWT compiler.

Comment: I guess that some workaround could be facilitated using /etc/hosts file by marking servers that GWT compiler is trying to reach as 127.0.0.1. It's weekend so I cannot tryout anything but on Monday or Tuesday I'll try to find some more information.

Comment: Or maybe some classpath problems are causing the initial need to compile with `-XdisableUpdateCheck` switch - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11563462/339219

Comment: This issue seems like a classpath issue, but can't seem to identify which set of libraries are causing the conflict, so I settled on hacking version 2.4 of the GWT Maven Plugin by hardcoding the "-XdisableUpdateCheck" to one of its internally objects responsible for passing the CLI options to the GWT compiler.